# Diferencia entre query() y execute()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Realmente es lo mismo:

```
$base->query("DELETE FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID='$Id'");
```

Que hacer esto:

```
$base->prepare("DELETE FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID='$Id'")->execute();
```

?

Comment: Tienes la respuesta en SO version inglesa: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700623/pdos-query-vs-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700623/pdos-query-vs-execute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cuando hacemos uso de las interfaces mysqli o PDO; podemos trabajar
>   las `queries` de los modos siguientes

1. `query()`. Cuando no necesitamos que nuestra consulta ejecute datos dinámicos; es decir el usuario no va a mandar variables que van a intervenir para mandar el resultado deseado

**EJEMPLO**

```
$data = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
```

2. `execute()`. Al momento que necesitamos que nuestro sistema responda a procesar consultas con datos dinámicos que el usuario manda en forma de variables; es necesario usar sentencias preparadas para procurar evitar ataques de inyección SQL

> **EJEMPLO PDO**

```
$id = 9;
$data = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id");
$data->execute([":id" => $id]);
$resultado = $data->fetch(PDO_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

> **EJEMPLO MYSQLI**

```
$id = 12;
$data = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
$data->bind_param("i", $id);
$data->execute();
```

> En cualquiera de los dos casos mysqli o PDO al momento de usar
>   sentencias preparadas; necesitamos hacer uso de: marcadores de nombre
>   `:nombre` o marcadores de posición `?` para indicar los datos
>   dinámicos que van a ser procesados en la consulta

Comment: Excelente aclaración. GRACIAS!

Answer (score 4):

De la forma que lo estas usando, si, el resultado es el mismo.

**PERO! No, no son y tampoco funcionan exactamente igual.**

[Las sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) sirven evitar [las inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597) escapando automáticamente los parámetros enlazados y al mismo tiempo "*optimizar*" la consulta si la misma se necesitara realizar en reiteradas oportunidades.

Supongamos el siguiente caso:

```
<?php
// CUIDADO: esto elimina la tabla EJ_TABLA 
$Id = "1'; DROP TABLE EJ_TABLA; SELECT * FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID='1";

// El resultado de hacer
$base->query("DELETE FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID='$Id'");

// Seria equivalente a
$base->query("DELETE FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID='1'; DROP TABLE EJ_TABLA; SELECT * FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID='1'");

// Lo cual claramente no es el resultado esperado

//----------

// En cambio si se usa correctamente (y suponiendo que estas usando MySQLi)
$stmt = $base->prepare("DELETE FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $Id);
$stmt->execute();

// Seria equivalente a 

$base->prepare("DELETE FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID='1\'; DROP TABLE EJ_TABLA; SELECT * FROM EJ_TABLA WHERE ID=\'1'")->execute();

// Si prestas atención, las comillas fueron escapadas, 
// se evito la inyección SQL y nada malo habrá pasado.
```